# Какие есть способы вытащить данные с сайта?

Tags: c#, парсер

Требуется спарсить сайт Auto.Ru на получение характеристик вообще всех автомобилей. Страница с которой мне надо достать данные выглядит так https://auto.ru/catalog/cars/volkswagen/polo/20113124/20554752/specifications/20554752_21495741_20726520/ в принципе проблемы вытащить их с этой страницы не составляет, но до этой страницы надо как-то ещё добраться, как мы понимаем данных очень много и всё это парсить по HTML не очень круто. Как сделать таких данных?)

Comment: [тыц](https://habr.com/ru/post/579336/)

Comment: Парсить по HTML не очень круто, когда есть более удобные способы. В данном случае публичные API и данные приходят именно в HTML.

Comment: `Какие есть способы` - а это не от вас зависит, а от конкретного ресурса. Если вам сайт дает только HTML, то только его вы и можете обрабатывать. Если сайт дает JSON данные, то вот уже у вас выбор между JSON и HTML и тут естественно JSON будет лучше. Если сайт еще и соккет имеет, то вот вам уже и HTML, JSON, да еще и соккет, выбирайте то что лучше и удобней. Конкретно сайт, что вы указали в вопросе, он имеет некий API, который возвращает JSON, внутри которого конкретный кусок данных в виде HTML. Сам API в виде простых GET запросов идет. И вот как бы, вариантов у вас нет больше.